# Invalid path Error while cloning into eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, github

Invalid Path: Housing-society/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.springframework.ide.ecplise.boot.dash:Cloud
Foundry.prefs

[image: This is the issue I encountered which I think is related to spring frameworks of which I have all the jar files of...please help me]

I think this has to do with the dependencies not being part of my own clone or some error related to spring Frameworks. Please do help.

Comment: Don't post text as image/link ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). Use [edit] option to correct your post.

Comment: Seems the git repo contains the eclipse dependencies too, which might be in conflict with your project settings. Better download the source and make a commit with project specific folders and not workspace metadata.

Comment: It sounds like the eclipse-specific files like .project and the .settings folder are part of the repo. They probably contain a path that doesnt exist in your clone and system

Comment: Are you using a filesystem that supports the colon as a valid filename character?

Answer (score 1):

The file name of the file mentioned in the error message contains a colon (`:`) which is allowed in a few file systems (see [e. g. here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/173529)), but in most, it is not (e. g. in Windows a file name must not contain `:`).

Answer (score 0):

The colon in the naming convention is unsupported. I had the same outcome on a git clone action and the invalid file was a static httpd document which disqualifies dependencies from being the cause. Try renaming the file directory in the git project